# What is a swap file?

Tags: unix, vi

Using vi I started editing a html file and I accidentally exited out of session, now when I try to edit the file again I receive this message :

> E325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name ".myfile.swp" While
>   opening file "myfile.html"
>                dated: Tue Jul  3 09:55:39 2012
>
> (1) Another program may be editing the same file.
>       If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
>       different instances of the same file when making changes.
>       Quit, or continue with caution.
>
> (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
>       If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r myfile.html"
>       to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
>       If you did this already, delete the swap file ".myfile.html.swp"
>       to avoid this message.
>
> Swap file ".myfile.html.swp" already exists!

Has any damage occured to myfile.html ?

What I think is occuring is that its storing a copy of the opened file when I exited my session (the swap file) ?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html):

> Vim stores the things you changed in a swap file.  Using the original
>   file you started from plus the swap file you can mostly recover your
>   work.

The documentation also describes [the recovery procedure](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html#recovery) in case you need it.

Comment: Maybe it goes without saying (but let's say it anyway), the recovery procedure works exactly the same with Vi